# Removing sign extension from an integer?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am attempting to construct a machine instruction `loadi` in binary format. The machine instruction itself consists of the opcode, which is `00000` the destination register, the immediate bit, and some constant value. It should look like so:

`00000 00 0 00000000`

Say we want to do the instruction `loadi 2 -123`. This would translate to the machine instruction:

`0000010110000101`

I am attempting to construct this machine code using bitshifting. I first shift on the destination register into the correct position. Then, I shift on the immediate bit value:

```
instr = (dr << 9); // Destination register
instr += (1 << 8); // Immediate bit value
```

This will generate:

`00000 10 1 00000000`

The last part that I need to add on to complete the instruction and generate the object code is the constant value `-123`. However, the issue is that when I try:

```
instr += constant;
```

It does not work. I do not need to do bitshifting here since I want it to start at the 0th place. After some testing I think the issue may be because `-123` is sign extended. I only want the first 8 bits.

Is there a simple method to retrieving the first 8 bits of `-123`?

All values in this question are represented by the type `int`. However, I am only using the first `16 bits`.

Comment: Use `unsigned` variables? When dealing with bits and not their typical decimal representations, then use of `unsigned` is highly recommended.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Would I still get the proper representation of `-123` appended onto the machine instruction I'm making?

Comment: `constant` could be `char` and you have to use `|=` operator, so it doesn't subtract from the entire instruction.

Comment: @LogicStuff Would you be able to explain that further for me?

Comment: That's weird, even when I try to shift or add the value on it won't add for some reason.

Comment: Add the types of your variables to the question.

Comment: @StormyGraveyard "Would I still get the proper representation of `-123`?" Maybe.  It depends on the proper representation of `-123`, and on the representation in the host machine.

Comment: @LogicStuff The types of the variables are integers. However, I am only using the first 16 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bit mask the value:

```
instr = (opCode << 11)
        | (reg << 9)
        | (1 << 8)
        | (value & 0xff);
```

In general: you might want to bit mask all of the values; that
would be logical.  But hopefully, `reg` and `opCode` will never
be values which could have the unused bits set.

Also: this will only work if both the target machine and the
host have the same representation for negative numbers, and that
representation is not signed magnitude.  (Of course, today, 2's
complement is almost universal.  But it might be worth checking
exactly how the `loadi` interprets its value field.)

Comment: Okay, so I tried this and I got the binary representation:

`00000 10 1 00101101` which generates the object code `1325`. It should be generating `1413`, so I believe something may be wrong with the constant. The decimal representation of `00101101` is 45, where it should be -123.